# Date attribute by JSF cross-field validation

Tags: validation, jsf, attributes

I'm passing an attribute to another field's validator.

JSF (Primefaces)

```
                    <p:column>
                        <p:calendar id="IncommingDate"
                                    pattern="dd.MM.yy"
......................................................
                                    binding="#{incommingDate}">
                        </p:calendar>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <p:calendar id="SolvDate"
                                    pattern="dd.MM.yy"
                                    value="#{complaintBean.solvDate}"
                                    showOn="button"
                                    showButtonPanel="true">
                            <f:validator validatorId="validation.SolvDateValidator"/>
                            <f:attribute name="complaintStatus" value="#{complaintStatus}"/>
                            <f:attribute name="incommingDate" value="#{incommingDate}"/>
                        </p:calendar>
                    </p:column>
```

SolvDateValidator.java

```
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException
    {
        logger.trace("SolvDateValidator:: Start validation");

        UIInput incommDate = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("incommingDate");
        
        Date incommingDate = (Date) (Objects.isNull(incommingDateUI.getSubmittedValue())
                    ? incommingDateUI.getValue()
                    : incommingDateUI.getSubmittedValue());
```

The incommingDate attribute is a date, but sometimes spontaneously it is passed as java.sql.Date ("18.10.2023") and sometimes as String ("Wed Oct 18 00:00:00 CEST 2023"). In the second case I get     certainly ClassCastException

Is there any way to rigidly set its type to avoid additional checks on the class of the object?

Comment: getSubmittedValue() is definitely not a Date. Component ordering is significant. See the first duplicate for in-depth explanation. The second duplicate contains full working code for your specific case.